# This simple use of JTable default cell editor to validate text does not work. Can someone help understand why?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to validate that data entered in a JTable cell is correct before letting the user end the editing. In the Oracle tutorial at this link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext
they make it sound very simple. An excerpt says

> The automatic checking of user-entered strings occurs when the default editor attempts to create a new instance of the class associated with the cell's column. The default editor creates this instance using a constructor that takes a String as an argument. For example, in a column whose cells have type Integer, when the user types in "123" the default editor creates the corresponding Integer using code equivalent to new Integer("123"). If the constructor throws an exception, the cell's outline turns red and refuses to let focus move out of the cell. If you implement a class used as a column data type, you can use the default editor if your class supplies a constructor that takes a single argument of type String.

To test this I created the simplest case I could think of, using this class:

```
    class CustomClass {
        int value = 0;
        public CustomClass(String newValue) throws NumberFormatException {
            value = Integer.parseInt(newValue);
            if(value<0 || value>100) throw new NumberFormatException("value out of range");
        }
        public String toString() {return value+"";}
    }
```

The main idea is that if the custom class has a constructor with just a string, and a toString() method, it should work. I set up the table with CustomClass as the type for the first column. It does not produce the expected or desired result. Any attempt edit those cells results in the cell being outlined in red, and editing cannot be completed. Which is the described behavior if the entered data is bad. 
This is what happens:

[image]

I do realize there are many other ways to do this. But this method was attractive because it offered the hope of using the default editor and renderer with very little extra work in the custom class (which I needed anyway). But it doesn't seem to work as advertised. I hope to be shown to be wrong ;-)

The complete program is pasted below. A couple of prints have been added to help me see what's happening, but they never print at expected time. That is, it seems the constructor and toString() method don't get called to validate and return the entered text. Anybody know why? Thanks.

-------------- complete test program -------------

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
final public class TestCodeGUI {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestCodeGUI window = new TestCodeGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public TestCodeGUI() {
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 370, 168);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 330, 103);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {new CustomClass("00"), Integer.parseInt("01"), "02"},
                {new CustomClass("10"), Integer.parseInt("11"), "12"},
                {new CustomClass("20"), Integer.parseInt("21"), "22"},
                {new CustomClass("30"), Integer.parseInt("31"), "32"},
            },
            new String[] {
                "Column 0", "Column 1", "Column 2"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                CustomClass.class, Integer.class, String.class
            };
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Initialize complete");
    }
}

class CustomClass {
    int value = 0;
    public CustomClass(String newValue) throws NumberFormatException {
        System.out.println("CustomClass constructor with \"" + newValue + "\"");
        value = Integer.parseInt(newValue);
        if(value<0 || value>100) throw new NumberFormatException("value out of range");
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s = value+"";
        System.out.println("CustomClass toString returning \"" + s + "\"");
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I’m aware of better layout managers, though not skilled with them. But mainly I was trying to keep the example of the question as terse as possible. Learning about layouts that better conform to the size and shape of the screen and window is on my list. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the JTable class where you will find the `GenericEditor` class which is the default editor for the table. The `stopCellEditing()` method is responsible for setting the red Border.

I tried to replicate the `stopCellEditing()` logic in your class with the following code:

```
System.out.println("Initialize complete");
System.out.println(table.getDefaultEditor(Object.class));
System.out.println(table.getDefaultEditor(CustomClass.class));

Class[] argTypes = new Class[]{String.class};
java.lang.reflect.Constructor constructor;
//Class<?> type = table.getColumnClass(column);
Class<?> type = CustomClass.class;

//String s = (String)super.getCellEditorValue();
String s = "25";

try
{
    //SwingUtilities2.checkAccess(constructor.getModifiers());
    constructor = type.getConstructor(argTypes);
    Object value = constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{s});
    System.out.println(value + " : " + value.getClass());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
    //((JComponent)getComponent()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
    //return false;
}
```

and the code seems to work correctly since a new CustomClass object is created. However, my code can't invoke the `SwingUtilities2.checkAccess(...)` method, so maybe that is where the problem is?

In any case, I don't see a problem with what you are testing. I guess you need to step through the real code using a debugger so see what is happening.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. But I confess I don't really get what you're trying to show me in the code snippet above. Your suggestion is good, and don't know why I haven't done it already. I'll read the GenericEditor code, and/or step through during execution, see where it's going bad. I was hoping I had some little flaw in my code that would be so obvious to others I'd get an immediate simple fix. I'll post here if I figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: OK double thanks. The problem was in fact simple and obvious in 20-20 hindsight. Your clue about checkAccess was the key. The CustomClass has to be public. Making it so is the fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to camickr for the clue to the answer. The JTable code uses introspection to access constructor and toString of the custom class, so that class must be public. Making it so fixes the problem. Thanks camickr. And thanks stackoverflow. My first question asked and aswered in 15 hours.